# How can I avoid a Div/0 error in my Excel (2010) pivot table when I'm calculating an EBIT Margin

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm using Excel 2010 have developed a pivot table for some financial modeling.  The model includes sales and expenses for shared services teams and sales teams. I'm trying to calculate a EBIT margin for the total company using a Calculated Item.  When I do this, I'm getting a DIV/0 error.

My formula is very straight forward:

```
(Sales - Expense) / Sales
```

I believe I'm getting the error because the shared services teams do not have sales, thus the Div/0 error.

Is there a way to force the formula to perform the calculation on an aggregate basis and thus avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

use the iferror-function

```
= IFERROR((Sales - Expense) / Sales, 0)
```